# Javascript, weird floating point number endless decimal?

Tags: javascript, floating-point

I need some help with floating point numbers...please!

Here's the thing, I have code like below:

```
<script>

    function add()
    {
        document.getElementById("answer").value = parseFloat(document.getElementById("num1").value) + parseFloat(document.getElementById("num2").value);
    }

    function subtract()
    {
        document.getElementById("answer").value = parseFloat(document.getElementById("num1").value) - parseFloat(document.getElementById("num2").value);
    }

    function multiply()
    {
        document.getElementById("answer").value = parseFloat(document.getElementById("num1").value) * parseFloat(document.getElementById("num2").value);
    }

    function divide()
    {
        document.getElementById("answer").value = parseFloat(document.getElementById("num1").value) / parseFloat(document.getElementById("num2").value);
    }

</script>
```

Sorry it's a bit long! And then the html is pretty simple:

```
<h1>Calculator</h1>

<h3>Enter a value in each box below, then click an operation</h3>

<form id="calculatorForm">
    <input id="num1" value="0" type="text">
    <input id="num2" value="0" type="text">
    <br>
    <input value="+" onclick="add();" type="button">
    <input value="-" onclick="subtract();" type="button">
    <input value="*" onclick="multiply();" type="button">
    <input value="/" onclick="divide();" type="button">
    <br>
    <input id="answer" value="0" type="text">
</form>
```

You can pretty much guess what my question is gonna be: when I multiply, divide, or subtract two floating point numbers, I end up with an infinite decimal.

I need a quick solution that will round those numbers to two decimal points, and I need it to work later on, because I then need to implement Fahrenheit-to-Celsisus operations afterwards.

I don't care how this is done, but it **must** be Javascript.  Sorry if this has been answered before, but I really need an answer soon! Thanks!

EDIT: **A BIG Thankyou to the helpful people who answered my questions. Thank you!**

Comment: Might not want to start your question off by saying you couldn't be bothered to read other questions that may answer yours.

Comment: A failure to plan on your part does not constitute an emergency on my part. Read the damned answers.

Comment: I'll have you know @Chris, I was given this code. I have to work with it. Thanks for your support.

Comment: So work with it -- by reading the answers. Laziness doesn't sit well with me.

Comment: @Chris, if you have nothing constructuive to say, please don't say anything. I'm new here, and very quickly will be gone from here if the likes of you are constantly trolling around the place.

Comment: This isn't a troll. This question has already been asked, and as per the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) this question shouldn't even be here.

Comment: Wow. Such a helpful site - so, this boils down to GIYF? Nice community.

Comment: user-Unknown: Did you consider that people may share his feelings?  When new to a site, perhaps you should try a bit harder to adhere to the rules/attitude of the site.  The spirit of this site is not "here's my homework!  Finish it!  Now!!!"  He was simply trying to point that out.  (Note to anyone who reads this: The original post, before editing had a much different tone than the one now.  It originally had something along the lines of "I can't be miffed to read any other posts, so do this for me")

Comment: there's an appropriate meme for describing your approach, @user-Unknown. It involves this sideways checkered baseball cap

Comment: In the past 6 years, I've seen way too many online communities centered around programming fall into the toilet because the sense of "we should all help each other!" turns into "do this for me, and do it now!"  So in this debate, I must side with Chris.  He did not attack you on a (overly) personal level; he, along with a few other people, simply pointed out that you are more likely to get a positive response if certain attributes of your question asking change.  Yes, I overstepped my boundaries of what is and isn't my business, but I do believe that Chris and others were justified.

Comment: @Corbin, at this moment, I can only assume Chris and kingjiv were responsible for deliberately downvoting my question, and I would like you to remember the time when you were once a new user and struggled to even get the privelege to up-vote, let alone even comment on someone else's post.  Chris didn't point out how to make my question positive, he said I was lazy, and quite clearly didn't like my question.

Comment: I actually did not.  I'm not yet comfortable with what does and does not deserve down votes, so I only down vote things that are blatantly against rules.  And I am new here (actively anyway, not in terms of first login).  Disclaimer: rude moment impending.  It's not our responsibility to tolerate your flaws while we try to fix them.  It's your responsibility to work on them on your own.  We're here to answer programming questions, not to help people learn how to politely interact with others.

Comment: Final Post: I'm not the one who needs to learn to be polite; though I will agree that next time I post, maybe I should have tried a little longer to figure out the issue - that said, when you're new to Javascript and have discovered a fantastic website like this, it's a little too easy to just post and see all the helpful answers come in, approaching the issue from different angles and allowing you to choose which one will work best.  Thankyou, Corbin, for at least not down-voting me, and I personally will never downvote **ever**, because every question is important in the author's eyes.

Comment: I've never downvoted anything (including this question), but this does meet both parts of the criteria for a downvote: "This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or unhelpful." There's obviously no research effort because the answer could've been found with Google or with the Stack Overflow search in less time than it took to post the question. It is _unclear_ because the title doesn't reflect what you're asking and you've included way more code than needed to explain the problem (and the HTML is completely irrelevant). And it is _unhelpful_ because it is a duplicate.

Comment: It's not good to assume people have downvoted you, I didn't.

Comment: My apologies, @kingjiv, I've since cooled down and am sorry if I wrongly accused you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `.toFixed()`:

```
var num = 45.34343434343;

num = num.toFixed(2); // "45.34"
```

Comment: Somebody helpful! Thanks so much! =D

Answer (score 3):

See here there is a function  `Number.toFixed(num)` that do just that.

See more info and other options at [W3Schools JS Numbers](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_number.asp).

That problem occurs because in Javascript every `Number` is 64bit floating-point, there no such thing as an `Integer`.

Answer (score 3):

Use the `.toFixed()` function in Javascript.

```
document.getElementById("answer").value = (parseFloat(document.getElementById("num1").value) - parseFloat(document.getElementById("num2").value)).toFixed(2);
```

Or an easier to see version:

```
var x = 3.14159265358979323;
alert(x.toFixed(2));   // 3.14
```

A very good description of how it works [on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed).

Comment: Another helpful person! Thanks! :D Glad to see you aren't all like @Chris.

Answer (score 3):

The `.toFixed()` is useful, but be ware that correctly rounding number in Javascript (and many other languages) require more work.

There are different rounding rules for "Tie-Breaking" and you need to know what is the one you need because they are used in different scenarios.
Look [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding).

Comment: Thank you, Max, have some extra reputation, because you are a helpful person. :-)